# Tensorflow and Keras Installation Problems JupyterLab / Anaconda (Debian)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip, anaconda3

I've been trying to install keras and tensorflow for Jupyter-lab (python).
I first tried with pip, but the notebook stopped functioning everytime I imported keras.
After some research on different feeds, I decided to uninstall it with pip and try to reinstall it with anaconda3.
Then, there was a path issue installing tensorflow with the conda command. So I researched more and wrote this in the terminal :

```
export PATH="/home/myname/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

I created another environment and could install tensorflow with (same for keras) :

```
conda activate myenv
conda install tensorflow
```

I came back on the local JupyterLab and imported keras. But it couldn't find the module named keras. I tried again with pip :

```
!pip install keras
import keras
```

And got the same :

```
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.9.0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 10>()

---> 10 import keras

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Is it a path problem ? How can I solve it ? I don't understand how it can find it, but not import it correctly.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Run `!conda list` within Jupyter and it will show you what packages are available in the environment.

Comment: I ran `!conda list` within Jupyter and found out neither keras nor tensorflow appeared. It checked there **/home/USERNAME/anaconda3**. I ran it in the terminal in this environment **/home/USERNAME/.conda/envs/myenv** and then tensorflow and keras came out. Do you know how I can solve this ?

Comment: Install the Jupyter Notebook extensions from the command line: `conda install nb_conda`. The *Notebook Conda Kernels* extension will allow you to choose an environment kernel for a notebook. See the documentation: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/use-jupyter-notebook-extensions/#notebook-conda-kernels

Answer (score 0):

After creating the virtual environment(myenv) in conda, open a new jupyter notebook in the same environment and you need to install `TensorFlow` in that environmnet using the below code:

```
!pip install tensorflow

import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

Now you can access the `Keras` from `TensorFlow` as below:

```
from tensorflow import keras
keras.__version__
```